# I am having "Request Entity Too Large error" with react-app on heroku?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, buildpack

I have deployed my react-app on heroku, and I know create-react-app-buildpack just allow 1mb file transfer. I have created a static.json in root directory:

```
{
  "max_body_size": "50m",
  "root": "build/",
  "https_only": true,
  "routes": {
    "/**": "index.html"
  }
}
```

Still, I have problem posting images larger than 1 MB! Please help if anyone has a solution?